# ActiveRecord internals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a good article or book chapter describing internal workings of ActiveRecord? I want to read a primer before digging into the source code.

Comment: If you are thorough with understanding of Ruby as a language, I would suggest just dive head first and read the code.

Comment: Use the source, Luke! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, its worth reading the source. Chapters 7 and 8 of [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) might help guide the way.